# If you have insurance of some kind, and you are in an accident, does that mean that they increase your monthly fee?

Tags: insurance

I've always been confused by things like this:

1. Joe has his car stolen or drives it into a wall by accident, or some other kind of accident happens which "goes on the insurance".
2. Joe gets money from his insurance company.
3. Joe says: "Nah! No big deal! It was all covered on my insurance!"

But isn't it a big deal after all? I cannot imagine that the insurance company just happily pays out money like that, with no downside to Joe. Their whole business is based on collecting monthly fees and not on paying out expensive new cars to clumsy/careless people.

Surely the company must punish Joe in some way, such as increasing the monthly fee that he has to pay? If not, a customer can cost them a fortune by continuously crashing cars by accident and getting new cars on the insurance.

So when Joe claims that it's "no big deal", how short-sighted can you get? Does he not even think of the next monthly insurance bill, which will now have an extra $50 added to it or something?

I'm asking this as a person who has never once in my life had any kind of insurance on anything. The whole concept of "insurance" always seemed strange to me. It seems like it would always be better to simply save money yourself, so that you can buy a new car in case there is an accident. That way, you don't perpetually pay a company even if there is never an accident, and you could use it for something else, etc. Since they are a business, they are obviously going to make more from the customer than they ever will pay out, so it seems almost like a polished scam to me.

I must be missing something.

Comment: see also [Why buy insurance?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/54561/why-buy-insurance) and [Does it make sense to insure something when you could financially bear its loss?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/84411/does-it-make-sense-to-insure-something-when-you-could-financially-bear-its-loss) and [the other high-voted posts in this tag](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insurance?tab=Votes)

Comment: So if you plan to buy a car, you always make sure you have enough money to buy *two* cars, because the first one might get totaled five minutes after you start driving it and you need to buy another one? (Or really, you need enough money to buy *three* cars, because something similar might also happen to the second one...)

Comment: @alephzero: So you buy cheap cars, and learn to do your own mechanical work.  Works for me: I've only once bought a car that cost me over $5K.  Only one of them ever needed immediate replacement, and that was covered by the other guy's insurance :-)

Comment: Insurance is tradeoff between expected value of outcome vs variance of the outcome.

Comment: @jamesqf Everything has a cost.  Cars that are old enough where insurance isn't needed lack the safety features of the newest cars.  Yes, you are saving money, at the risk of a fatal accident which in a modern car you would walk away from without a scratch.  Particularly if you are talking about cars where the average person can still perform most mechanical work, those are significantly less safe than a car < 5 years old.  Again, expected value vs. variance.  Very bad accidents are rare, but if you are in one you will massively regret your choice or be too dead to be able to.

Comment: Forgot to add, OP, the thing you are missing is that cars can cause an enormous amount of damage.  Literal millions in worst case scenarios, but even ignoring those you could potentially be responsible for 100's of thousands in damages.  Do you have 100k you can toss away if you run off the road, hit a person or two and demolish a storefront?  Once again, EV vs V.  Bad outcomes are rare but tail events are unimaginably expensive to fix.

Comment: You've also missed the concept of an *excess*: the insurance doesn't usually cover all the value, you'll have to pay a sum yourself, usually in the $100-$1000 range. And of course if you're making an unusual number of claims you will likely be investigated for fraud.

Comment: "Their whole business is based on collecting monthly fees and not on paying out expensive new cars to clumsy/careless people. Surely the company must punish Joe in some way" — newsflash: sometimes bad things happen without anyone being clumsy or careless. That's what insurance is for: to stop bad luck ruining people's lives. The business is based on predicting how often bad things will happen, using data and maths, and charging enough to still make money.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, this is why it's usually *not* advisable to get added insurance on items that aren't terribly expensive and have fixed replacement costs (like for some electronics or appliances). If you can cover the cost yourself without too much burden, you're usually better off paying it yourself. Car and home insurance are generally worthwhile, since you may be on the hook for hundreds of thousands or millions of dollars very suddenly, which would financially ruin most people if they didn't have insurance.

Comment: @eps: While older cars may lack some supposed "safety" features of newer ones, they also lack many anti-safety features like "infotainment" touch screens causing distracted driving, power doors that trap people inside, or self-driving software that takes the car under semitrailers or rams fire engines.  Passive safety features are IMHO highly over-sold, given that something like 90% of "accidents" are due to driver error.  People need to learn how to drive so they DON'T run off the road, hit people, or demolish storefronts.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/121763/how-do-insurers-justify-raising-premiums-after-no-fault-claims).

Comment: Only one answer has mentioned moral hazard so far

Comment: The purpose of insurance is to make the unpredictable, predictable.  Warranty and insurance lets you **budget** your automotive expenses as monthly or annual expenses, reducing pressure on your emergency fund. Moving a car down the street is no different than moving a house or barge down the street, you are responsible for all the damage or injury it may do.  That can run into the millions of dollars if you really hurt someone.  Sure you want to carry that as a cash reserve?

Comment: @jamesqf for anybody who is like me, trying to perform mechanical work of almost any kind would most likely be MORE expensive due to lack of sufficient mechanical ability and the need to have a professional fix not only the original problem but my attempt making it worse.

Comment: You should really learn the distinction between _collision_ coverage - which protects _other_ people financially from the problem _you_ caused _them_ - such liability can be hundreds of thousands of dollars or _more_ - and _comprehensive_ coverage which protects _you_ from the problem you caused.  _Collision_ is required by states in order to get your car registered.  _Comprehensive_ is up to you - unless you're get a bank loan on your car or you're leasing it, then the bank/lessor requires it because _it isn't your car!_  It's _comprehensive_ you can forgo if you think you can afford to.

Comment: (And the same goes for _homeowners_ insurance (and _tenants_ insurance).  You get it to protect _other_ people from problems you're responsible for.  It's optional whether you get coverage for _your own_ goods.)

Comment: @Michael: Of course there's a learning curve, as with anything.  But it's not all that difficult to learn.  I go with Heinlein: "Specialization is for insects."

Comment: @davidbak: I think you have your terms slightly mixed up.  Liability insurance is what pays other people for damages you cause, and is required by law (in most places).  Collision & comprehensive (often abbreviated to C&C) pays for damage to your car, regardless of the cause: you might drive it into a concrete barrier, a tree might fall on it, it gets caught in a hailstorm or forest fire, whatever.  If you have an auto loan, it's almost certainly required by the lender.  If you pay cash, then as with extended warranties and such, you're better off foregoing it.

Comment: NB: Sometimes people refrain from claiming certain damages on their insurance, because the (expected) increase in premium would be more expensive than the damage covered.

Comment: For small to medium claims, (less than say, $3000) they will basically add at least some of it on to your future premiums, and you will pay it off over 3-4 years. Since they communicate with each other, moving insurers will not help. If someone sideswipes your parked car, you may as well just get it fixed yourself.

Answer (score 35):

Insurance is all a big numbers game, based on the concept of pooling losses. Certainly, insurance companies would love to collect money and never pay out, but in reality, they will have to pay out claims, because that financial security is the product they are selling.

In the case of Joe, he signed a policy after the insurance company assessed his level of risk and determined the "fair" premium he should pay in order to be covered in the event of an accident. He then is owed to be *indemnified* (compensated to restore loss) at least up to the level dictated in his policy.

Going forward from the accident however, Joe may see his rates increase. This is not a "punishment" per se, but is a re-assessment of his risk level given he had a recent accident. Over time, with no more incidents, his rates should return to a more normal level.

> It seems like it would always be better to simply save money yourself, so that you can buy a new car in case there is an accident.

This is a concept known as *Self Insurance* and is a viable option for the wealthy, barring no legal requirement for insurance, which most states have for cars. However, the vast majority of people don't have the ability to save in that capacity. Property damage to one's own car is only a portion of the possible exposure, as you have to consider the other person's car, and possible medical bills of both parties (including any passengers). To put it in perspective, the minimum amount of insurance required for many states is around $25,000 (for just the other party's damages when you're at fault), while common policies can go upwards of $100,000 or more.

Comment: It also might well depend on the circumstances of the accident.  For instance, if Joe drives his car into a wall, and the police arrest him for DUI, then it's a good bet his rate will go up substantially.  If he just gets a moving violation, it might go up a bit (and the same is true even if he didn't wreck the car and make a claim).  But if someone else hit him (e.g. rear-ended at a light) then it might well not change.  As you say, it's all about the insurance company's assessment of Joe's risk.

Comment: Even most states that require insurance, will allow you to 'self insure' by posting a bond for a required amount.

Comment: OTOH, some companies have the policy/idea of accident forgiveness, where 1 accident is overlooked. Sometimes this has a time limit, so if you don't have another accident in 5-10 years (or whatever), they will overlook another accident. And this is only if it's your fault. Your insurance doesn't raise your rates if the other person is at fault. So no, an insurance company may not actually raise rates if someone gets in an accident.

Comment: Another option the insurance company has if you have too many claims is to decline to offer you a renewal when your policy is next set to expire.

Comment: *legal requirement for insurance, which most states have for cars*, I think most places require *liability* insurance, but surely they don't require people to insure self-inflicted damage to your own car?

Comment: Self insurance is very common for medium to large companies and governments. All of my previous employers were self-insured because they did have $1 million (and more) lying around.

Comment: @gerrit I'm not sure about the US but because the liability component is the largest risk, the extra premium to insure against the the owner's loss is minimal.  Say I own a car worth €500, and crash it into a brand new Ferrari - my insurance has to pay for a Ferrari, in comparison to which my own car is rounding error.

Comment: ...Here in the UK, liability is called "third party only" (TPO) and is legally required.  "Third party fire and theft" is more common, insuring against a couple of likely causes of total loss.  "Comprehensive" covers more risks.  Unless you're regarded as an unusually high risk, TPO is often more than third party fire & theft because there's more competition for the latter.  In many cases comprehensive is also about the same (though not for young/new drivers), and some insurers won't cover vehicles over a certain value with anything other than comp (other insurers will be expensively)

Comment: Liability is likely to be worse in the US (huge hospital/legal bills) than here

Comment: I'd separate and highlight a bit more the nuances of at-fault claims, insurance (collision, comprehensive) for your own car, and 3rd party liability.  It's relatively easy to drive a junker or even a decent vehicle and replace it out of pocket for many people (not everybody); however it is exceptionally rare that someone can afford to cover liability out of pocket.  For my area my $2,000 car legally requires $200,000 liability, my broker recommends $1-2M and it is not uncommon for people to be covered up to $5M for liability.

Comment: @ChrisH Not in the US. You crash into a Ferrari, your insurance will pay up to the limits of coverage. Mandatory property damage liability can be as low as $5000, or typically $30k, depending on state law. Many people purchase the minimum requirements since they have minimal assets to sue over. If you owned a Ferrari, you'd likely buy uninsured/underinsured motorist coverage to fill the gap. This is reasonable as if you're driving an excessively expensive car, you're not imposing huge risk on other road users.

Answer (score 11):

You're missing a number of things.  Last I knew, New Hampshire is the only state that does not require car insurance, that is if you can prove that you can pay for the damages you cause. Furthermore, driving without car insurance is illegal and has penalties ranging from fines to even jail time.

In addition, car insurance covers medical payments for you and your passengers as well as liability coverage for damage to the other driver’s property and medical injuries if you are at fault (up to the limits of your policy).

Your concern for being charged $50 more per month is misplaced.

Comment: Exactly. Hospital bills for people far exceed the cost of repairing or replacing a vehicle. They could easily rack up over $150k in medical bills for any surgery and physical therapy. Especially if there's multiple people involved.

Comment: Virginia does not require insurance but requires payment of $500 "uninsured vehicle fee" along with annual registration if you don't. This makes it possible to get in a situation where there's nobody who's both liable and able to pay.

Comment: What about other countries? It looks like asker didn't specify where they live.

Comment: This sounds unlikely.  Of all the states in the world, only New Hampshire does not require insurance?  I don't claim to know the situation in Argentina, Somalia, Eswatini, or Bougainville, but the claim in this answer seems very strong.

Comment: @gerrit: New Hampshire is a subdivision of the USA, the answer obviously does not cover other countries (which is the word an American would use instead of "states" to talk about Argentina etc.)

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Other countries may also have subdivisions called states (Estados Unidos Mexicanos comes to mind)

Answer (score 6):

Self-insure when you can afford to do so (i.e., don't buy consumer warranties) because the money saved by not buying the extended warranty will be more than the expense of the few times where it could have helped.

But DON'T self-insure when a single hit can significantly impact your finances and/or make it impossible to replace the item, such as home insurance, auto liability, or comprehensive/collision insurance on a new(ish) car.

Comment: Not sure about the final point; maybe I can't replace a €25,000 car, but maybe I *can* buy an old wreck or get around by bicycle + transit + occasional car rental.  Full insurance on items you can't afford to replace is only needed if the item is essential (such as a home, which most people are required to insure due to mortgage rules anyway).

Comment: @gerrit if you're happy too, I suppose, then sure. I think most people wouldn't be if they were willing to spend $25K on a car to begin with.

Comment: @gerrit: But even though I could replace a €25,000 car, I wouldn't have bought one in the first place :-)  At least in the US, most people who buy cars in that price range take out loans, and as with mortgages, C&C insurance is required by the lender.

Comment: You are correct that most people who buy cars in that range take out loans. (Heck, I'm sure that's even true for half the price.) But we have two very small kids and bought the family minivan new a couple years ago. Over $30K. We paid cash, and we have to cash to replace it if necessary, but you better believe that we got C&C insurance on it even without any lender requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly.  It just depends on how the insurance company rates the insured and the nature of the claim.

But often a claim will result in a higher premium but there is no certainty either way.

Having insurance is not a license to be stupid because the insurance company is in the business to make a profit.  One drawback to filing claims that the company finds to be questionable is that they may drop you at the next renewal rather than raise your rates.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can in effect be “punished” for making too many claims by seeing your premiums increase. In many countries, there is even a national risk scale based on driving history shared by all insurers. Depending on local regulations, insurers can also go as far as kick out some clients.

The more interesting thing is that even before getting into your first accident, the mere fact that you are insured might change your behavior and incite you to take more risk than you otherwise would have (that's related to the broader concept of [*moral hazard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_hazard)). Excess or deductible is one way to deal with that, as are risk scales that give you a “bonus” or reward after several years of driving without a claim.

This is actually a very general problem: Insurance always has an effect on the behavior of the policyholders and therefore their risk profile. Insurance contracts are designed to mitigate this. Insurance mandates and reinsurance or risk compensation schemes also help with this. This can work relatively well, especially if insurance is effectively mandatory, but it does sometimes result in a completely dysfunctional insurance market.

So you are right that many insurances that are advertised do not always make a lot of sense for individual consumers. Health or car insurance mostly do, because the risks can be very high and regulation ensures the premiums remain manageable without rewarding risky behavior (or at least not too much).

Comment: The problem here is that you seem to assume that there inevitably will be a first accident, in which you're at fault.

Comment: @jamesqf I am not sure I follow your logic. Where do I rely on that assumption?

Comment: "... even before getting into your FIRST (emphasis mine) accident..."

Comment: @jamesqf That sentence is precisely about what happens when you haven't had an accident, it doesn't assume an accident is inevitable, quite the opposite. I write “even before” to contrast it with the notion that you only get careless after having experienced a successful claim directly.

Answer (score 1):

That heavily depends on the type of insurance and probably on the jurisdiction.

As you don't specify a location, I'll take Germany as an example.

Car liability insurances as well as "full car insurances" have a premium discount for lack of damages. The longer you are free of damages, the cheaper they get. If something happens, you lose part of or all the discount.

Other insurances don't have that, but can kick you out if you are too big a cost factor for them.

E. g., break your neighbour's lamp, then two other small things and have it all be covered with your private liability insurance. Then you might be out of luck if you injure someone with your bike which can be very expensive.

Comment: Car insurance in the UK is similar. The "no claims discount" increases over time and can be as high as 60% or more.  Depending on the insurer You don't necessarily lose it for just *one* claim, but for a series of claims in a relatively short time. Note this applies to claims independently of *who was at fault* for the insurance claim.

Comment: @alephzero Since we're talking about UK motor insurance it's also worth mentioning *no-claims discount protection* - customers can choose to pay a higher premium and in return the insurer penalises them less for each claim they make.

Answer (score 0):

> "or some other kind of accident happens which "goes on the insurance"

Some types of accidents aren't a big deal because they were caused by other people and you have some kind of proof of that like a police report or the area of the car damaged indicates somebody else did it (like major rear end damage). Your rate won't go up in those cases. Even if the other party isn't insured your state or insurance company will go after them for the money. For example I was in a long line of cars that had a chain reaction accident caused by a drunk driver. That drunk didn't have insurance but the state sued them for the money to pay the insurance companies for the damages. So eventually the insurance company can get back some of the loss that way in many cases. And keep in mind also that the insurance company has also priced their services based on the area where the insured lives and drives so they know the risks of things like car theft in that area and they make sure to collect enough money from everybody in that area to cover it.  The point is that the insurance company doesn't always need to raise rates.

Now if **you** cause an accident you would be wise to pay for it out of your own pocket instead of reporting it, whenever possible.

Comment: Not reporting an accident to your insurance is almost always a breach of your policy, and may result in any future claims being denied.  Be very, very careful with that.

Comment: @throx That seems to be jurisdiction-dependent. In Germany, the car liability insurance tells you on every bill the threshold under which it is cheaper to pay it on your own. You must only report it if you want them to pay for it.

Comment: @throx "any future claims" regarding that accident, yes. I'm yet to see a policy which would deny "any future claims" on an unrelated accident which I do report.

Answer (score 0):

Most car insurance companies will punish clients which file many claims. They may phrase it as "reward programs" for safe driving but it's the same in the end: people who have more accidents end up paying more. In some countries, such reward/penalty schemes are even mandated by the law.

For this reason it may sometimes be wise to fix minor accidents without using your insurance: if you crack a headlight, you might be better off paying $300 to get it replaced out of your own pocket rather than making your insurance pay for it. If the insurance increases your premium by $50 for a year (because you lose your "safe driving bonus"), you will pay $600 in the end.

You still need insurance in case you hit a pedestrian and are on the hook for paying up their medical bills. No amount of missed insurance bonuses will compensate for the amount of money your insurance might have to pay for you.

Comment: In my experience, the "safe driving" benefit is usually based on getting too many traffic tickets, not on damage claims like this.

Comment: @Barmar You have a rather unusual experience. In the UK, you have a _no-claims bonus_: After your first year on full premium, your 2nd year gets a substantial reduction (because of no-claims). 3rd year even more. If you ever make a claim, you lose the bonus and go back to full premium.

Comment: Your hypothetical situation with the headlight seems pretty outlandish to me. While I might agree with you that it could be worth it to fix minor damage out of pocket it seems incredibly unlikely that your premium would rise that much based on a single minor claim. If it was part of a pattern of claims that show you to be a high risk client then maybe, but if my insurance increased by $600 per year because of replacing a cracked headlight I would just find a different insurance company

Comment: Raising rates due to an accident is not punishment, it is simply a re-evaluation of your statistical risk of getting into future accidents.  It's one of many factors - age, traffic tickets, where you live, &c - that insurance companies use in setting rates.  (And $300 to replace a headlight?  What the heck are you driving, a Rolls Royce?)

Comment: @jamesqf Of course, I mean "punish" figuratively. And yes, according to Google "the average cost of replacing a headlight assembly ranges from $250 to $700" in the US for common cars, and around $1500 for a Rolls Royce. I wonder what car you have if it was so much cheaper for you.

Comment: @Kevin My insurance would increase the premium by $60 a year for that, but then it will take quite a while to get rid of it, between 1 year for a driver who had no accident in the last 10 years and 10 years for a novice driver. I'll end up overpaying the same $600 for a headlight if I start reporting every scratch.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev: Doing a quick look at my local auto parts store, a bulb for my Miata runs about $15-30 (though I've never needed to replace one).  For my Toyota pickup, $15-20.

Comment: @jamesqf There's a difference between "bulb" and "headlight". The latter includes the outer cover, mirrors, lenses, etc. It's pretty unusual for a car accident to break just the bulb.

Answer (score 0):

Many good answers already, but I'll touch on some points which I don't see mentioned.

- Insurance is only about *unpredictable accidents*. If they can prove you set the whole thing up and did deliberate damage, then that's called an "insurance fraud" and there's jail time to go with that.
- Even without deliberately causing damage you could still be reckless and insurance policies usually have some clauses that allow them not to pay out in such cases. This is, of course, a slippery slope since "reckless" can be a subjective thing and there have been cases where an insurance company abuses this clause. In general though it's fairly rare.
- If you do play honestly however, your insurance rate *usually* doesn't go up after a single accident, although the insurance companies do reserve the right to change it at any time for any reason. And they are quite likely to if you have multiple accidents in a short amount of time (meaning that they got something wrong when they estimated your risks).
- All in all it's a number game for the company. As long as it estimates the risks correctly and charges *just a bit more*, it will always come out on top regardless in the long run.
- As for whether or not to get insurance - that's a difficult question. *Someone* will have to pay if an accident happens. Can you afford it? Do you want to risk it? In the end, you can't insure *everything* in your life, so you'll have to take *some* risks. Which ones? It's clear that *on average* people would be better off without insurance... but that's only *on average*. If you happen to get unlucky, an insurance policy might actually turn out to be a lifesaver. Nobody can predict the future, not even insurance companies, so it's up to you to decide what to insure and what to risk in your own personal life.
- Different insurance companies can charge significantly different rates for the same insurance, so it can pay off to go around shopping. But be careful, because the devil's in the details. All of the following and more will affect the price: What risks are covered; how big the pay-out will be; what are the exceptions; how they estimate your risks; what the competition looks like; how likely they are to pay out (some companies offer dirt cheap insurance but then fight tooth and nail when it comes to paying up, others do the opposite); etc.